# Is a Niven ring in the atmosphere of Uranus stable?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, atmospheric-science, stability

For my science fiction universe, I need to mine a lot of Deuterium and Helium-3.

I have 10,000 intake fans each capable of 3,000 gigaliters an hour pushing atmosphere through 5 billion diffusers. This yields about 7 exagrams of Deuterium and 2 exagrams of Helium-3 a year. All the diffusers take up a lot of space, enough space that I could build a multilevel ring around Uranus. Obviously the ring would be in the atmosphere, around the 1 bar altitude.

My question is, would the atmosphere make a Niven ring in this case, stable? You would have air friction and the atmosphere would increase in density as the ring gets closer to the center. I was also wondering what the radius of the ring would need to be in order to be at the 1 bar level.

Comment: No offence intended, just some comments for clarity:  Could you not find out from,  Wikipedia or NASA websites,the density profile of Uranus **yourself**, so you could calculate what altitude 1 bar is at?  I do really like Niven's books, but I think you should consider moving this to engineering or world building,  as there are no obvious physics concepts here to explain.